# Wordpress: Why isn't my stylesheet being enqueued?

Tags: css, wordpress, overriding, external-script

I'm modifying an existing WP plugin by making a separate plugin that will extend it. I'd like to write CSS that will override the plugin. However, when I try to enqueue the stylesheet it doesn't work. I know it doesn't work because I added a simple form in the `includes()` and tried to style the words red in order to see a change. Why isn't this working??

Note - I'm using the action hook `plugins_loaded`, which I read in the codex happens before `wp_enqueue_script`. So I don't suspect that my enqueueing is missing the timing, but I'm new to WP dev so correct me if I'm wrong.

**Update** - Please see my updated CSS code below. The #id selector wasn't coloring the text red *by itself*, but when I added the p (paragraph selector) it worked. Neither selector worked by itself, it only worked when I added both. Why is this?

**find-do-for-anspress.php**

```
if (! defined('WPINC')) {
    die;
}

Class Find_Do_For_Anspress {

    /**
     * Class instance
     * @var object
     * @since 1.0
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Get active object instance
     *
     * @since 1.0
     *
     * @access public
     * @static
     * @return object
     */
    public static function get_instance() {

        if ( ! self::$instance ) {
            self::$instance = new Find_Do_For_Anspress(); }

        return self::$instance;
    }
    /**
     * Initialize the class
     * @since 2.0
     */
    public function __construct() {

        if ( ! class_exists( 'AnsPress' ) ) {
            return; // AnsPress not installed.
        }
        if ( ! defined( 'FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR' ) ) {
            define( 'FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ); 
        }

        if ( ! defined( 'FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_URL' ) ) {
            define( 'FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_URL', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
        }

        $this->includes();

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'fd_enqueue'));


}

    private function includes() {

        require_once (FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'braintree/lib/braintree.php');
        require_once (FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'fd-braintree/fd-bt-keys.php');
        require_once (FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'fd-braintree/fd-process-trans.php');
        require_once (FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'fd-braintree/fd-bt-functions.php');
        require_once (FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'fd-braintree/fd-bt-form.php');
        require_once (FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'includes/fd-ask-form.php');



    }

    public function fd_enqueue() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fd_for_anspress_css', FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'css/fd-css.css', array(jquery), null); //handle, source, dependencies, version, media (the type of media for which the stylesheet is designed, e.g. mobile, web, print...)
        //wp_enqueue_script( 'fd_for_anspress_js', FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'fd-braintree/js/fd-braintree-js.js', array(), null);  used require_once to directly add it to fd-bt-form.php
    } 

} //End class

function find_do_for_anspress() {
    $FDClassStart = new Find_Do_For_AnsPress();
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'find_do_for_anspress' );

        //HTML "testing" block
        echo '<p id="checkout">Testing the enqueued CSS</p>';
```

**fd-css.css attempt 1**

```
<style>
#checkout {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

**fd-css.css attempt 2**

```
<style>
#checkout {

    color: red;
}

p {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are are calling `wp_enqueue_style` you are passing `array(jquery)` as a dependency. With `jquery` being an invalid handle (it should be wrapped in quotes), the dependency is never loaded, so your stylesheet isn't loaded

That said, you likely don't want any dependencies for you CSS. You would use this if you wanted to control the load order of your stylesheets, any handle you place here would be loaded before your script. If the handle is invalid, your script won't be loaded.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'fd_for_anspress_css', FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'css/fd-css.css' );
```

Comment: Ah ok. I left the jquery part as a result of my testing. Using your line of code, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Might there be a way to test each part of the enqueue process to see where it might be getting stuck?

Comment: Your "testing" HTML block will be loaded above the head - you are calling it before you are even enqueuing the style. Did you view the source to see if it's really not there or just not applying to your test?

Comment: The "testing" block is definitely there, it's just not being colored red. That's how I know the CSS isn't being enqueued properly. But I don't see what can be going wrong.

Comment: I'm sure it's visible, but it's probably before you HTML tag? Definitely not in the BODY.

Comment: [I made some changes and now the HTML block is in the BODY](http://imgur.com/TYi5D7b) (I'll update my code accordingly). However, it's still not working. Would it be important to note that the plugin was already doing it's own enqueueing?? And also that I'm using `require_once()` to include an entire PHP library from Braintree? the Braintree API was giving my problems with an AJAX response in my main page, figured I should probably put that out there.

Comment: Note - by "the plugin was already..." I mean the previously existing plugin. I am writing my own plugin from scratch in order to extend that previously existing plugin.

Comment: I can't say what's wrong, but I can tell from your screenshot that something isn't correct. You have a body tag about your script/stylesheet/meta tags, which isn't the right order.

Comment: Your testing block is still not in the HTML body. It will be printed when your plugin is loaded, much before it should. Try adding it in an action attached to `wp_footer`.

Comment: [I asked a question on WP SE and they responded saying that scripts within the body tag are normal](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207226/normal-for-scripts-to-be-loaded-after-body-tag/207227#207227). Also, did you see my screenshot in a previous comment: "I made some changes...". You can see in that screenshot that the testing block is actually the first thing after the body tag.

Comment: You have it backwards, scripts in the body are fine, HTML in the header is not.

Comment: By "header" do you mean the `<head>` element of the page? If so, I opened that up and there is nothing in there that I have added personally. [It looks like more of just Wordpress's code up there](http://imgur.com/7ssqgFp).

Comment: My testing block is at the top of the page, yes, but that's just because the plugin that generates the rest of the page is doing its own thing and I did not put my code inside that plugin's code. If I did, the testing block might have appeared lower on the page.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I see what youre saying now. Someone explained it in another question. The browser moves the `<body>` tag when there is something in the wrong place. That's why it looked like (at least to me, the novice) the testing block was correctly in the `<body>` section.